# Is there any close event for MSAL popup?

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-msal

I am using `msal.js` to authenticate users by using `acquireTokenPopup` method. So, when the user closes the login popup(browser window) without logging in, I want to do an operation in my app. Is there any close event for the popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no close event for popup because when login popup closes then the browser event triggers. To trigger an event in your app you would need to handle the JavaScript window object event called [onbeforeunload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741880(v=vs.85)). This event will trigger when the browser window is closed.

Here is the sample code:

`window.onbeforeunload = function () {`
`};`

Here is a closed [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/706) referring to this issue reported on GitHub.